# Вставка файлов разного типа из буфера обмена

Tags: java, clipboard

Можете подсказать как вставлять файлы разного типа(ехе, txt, word и т.д.) и каталогов из буфера обмена? 
В примерах из гугла попадается в основном информация по копированию-вставке текста. А мне нужны именно файлы и каталоги.
Списки файлов и директорий реализованы с помощью List'а, соответственно вставляемый файл видимо должен добавляться как новый элемент листа, а потом обновлять его отображение...

Comment: непонятно куда нужно файл ставить

Comment: В реальную директорию, которые отображаются в программе с помощью List'a.

Comment: `ctrl +c -> ctrl +v`. тогда причем тут метка java?  я не понимаю, что вы хотите делать

Comment: @SeniorPomidor программа работает аналогично ТоталКоммандеру, делаю сейчас функции копирования-вставки файлов и каталогов. Каталоги и файлы отображаются с помощью компонента JList. Копирование в буфер выбранного из листа файла или каталога получилось, вставка - пока нет.